# Why `>>` works if Haskell is lazy?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm Learning Haskell now. [I read](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-monad-type-class) that the definition of `>>` is:

```
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b  
x >> y = x >>= \_ -> y
```

Cool. However, if `x` is not being used and Haskell is lazy, why does this print "hi"?

```
ghci> print "hi" >> return "end"
"hi"
"end"
```

A similar construct only returns "end" and never resolves the 1st argument, due to laziness:

```
ghci> skip _ r = r
ghci> skip (print "hi") "end"
"end"
```

I understand that `>>` must work as it is doing because otherwise monads would lose its meaning. But I don't understand *why* it actually works.

Comment: `a >> b` does not run a and then `b`. `a >> b` constructs a "recipe" that will first run `a` and then `b`.

Comment: `x` is being used (at least when `m` is `IO` like in your example), it is only the `_` that is not being used.

Comment: `x >> y` does not mean "evaluate expression `x`, discard the result, and then return `y`". Here `x` represents an IO action that when _run_ 1) performs side effects, and then 2) provides a value. The operator `x >> y` discards 2) but combines 1) with the effects of `y`. Note that merely evaluating an IO action (e.g. `seq (print 1) "hi"`) does _not_ run it. Calling the action at the GHCi prompt is one of the very few things that actually runs actions.

Comment: `>>=` is not simply function application. The argument passed to `\_ -> y` is not (necesarily) `x`, but something determined by the definition of `>>=` in whatever monad you are using.

Comment: Don't confuse `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` with `Data.Function.(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`. The former has to do *something* with its first argument in order to apply the second argument to a value of type `a`; the latter does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this becomes clearer if we write it with a transparent toy model for the `IO` monad, which is only capable of expressing `putStrLn` statements and trivial `return`s:

```
data PIO a = PIO { linesToPrint :: [String]
                 , returnVal :: a }

print' :: Show a => a -> PIO ()
print' x = PIO { linesToPrint = [show x]      -- ⸨1⸩
               , returnVal = () }
```

Notice that we already “ignore” `x` here in the sense that it doesn't make it into the `returnVal` in any way, but it does make it into the list which corresponds to what appears on the user's screen.

`PIO` is a monad in the following way: (it is actually the standard [writer monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#g:1))

```
instance Functor PIO where
  fmap f (PIO ls rv) = PIO ls $ f rv          -- ⸨2⸩
instance Applicative PIO where
  pure = PIO []                               -- ⸨3⸩
  PIO ls f <*> PIO ms x = PIO (ls++ms) $ f x  -- ⸨4⸩
instance Monad PIO where
  PIO ls x >>= f = PIO (ls++ms) y             -- ⸨5⸩
   where PIO ms y = f x
```

And of course still

```
  x >> y = x >>= \_ -> y                      -- ⸨6⸩
```

Now let's evaluate your example by hand:

```
      print' "hi" >> return' "end"
⸨1⸩      ≡ PIO ["hi"] () >> PIO ["end"]
⸨6⸩      ≡ PIO ["hi"] () >>= \_ -> PIO ["end"]
⸨5⸩      ≡ PIO (["hi"]++ms) y
            where PIO ms y = (\_ -> PIO ["end"] ()) ()
⸨β-rd⸩   ≡ PIO (["hi"]++ms) y
            where PIO ms y = PIO ["end"] ()
⸨inl⸩    ≡ PIO (["hi"]++["end"]) ()
⸨++⸩     ≡ PIO ["hi", "end"] ()
```

Notice in particular how the `["hi"]` has already made it into the result before we ever consider the β-reduction of the `_` argument coming from the definition of `>>`. This demonstrates that the return value can't possibly matter for whether or not `"hi"` is printed (though it could at this point still have an influence on what will be printed afterwards).

Comment: Thanks! This step by step evaluation really helps! What do you mean by "β-reduction"?

Comment: I mean, you could have literally [looked that up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B2-reduction)... β-reduction is just function application, inlining the applied argument (`()` in this case) to everywhere the parameter appears (`_`, which doesn't appear at all).

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption that "`x` is not being used" is mistaken.

The *result* of `x` is not used, but `x` itself is. The key insight here is that `x` is not a value as such, but a "recipe" of sorts that, when executed, will produce a value. This "recipe" itself is, confusingly, *also* a value of type `IO a`, but it's not the same value as `a`, which would be the result of executing `x`.

The way such "recipes" `IO a` are executed is magic. Basically the only way to execute `IO a` is to make it the value of `main` - the program entry point. Then the Haskell runtime will execute that value when the program is run.

The `main` value itself may be constructed in a variety of ways. One way could be the `>>` operator. This operator creates a new `IO a` value, which, when executed, will first execute its left argument and then its right argument. Executing `IO a` values one after another is also magic. This magic hides in the `>>=` operator.

Comment: IO is magic, but the magic is not particularly relevant to the question. We have other monads besides IO that exhibit the behavior described here, where `x` will be used despite its result being fed to a function that ignores its argument.

Comment: @DanielWagner that is because those monads define a `>>` operator that does not ignore its left argument

Comment: @user253751 Sometimes. And sometimes there is just a genuine data dependency in `>>=`, as in [StateT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.html#line-229) or [Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-157).

Comment: @DanielWagner well, that is the same as defining a >> operator that does not ignore its left argument.

Comment: @user253751 Okay. I'm not sure what the goal of your comment was, then. Are you claiming that because of this, the magic of `IO` is relevant? If so, I don't see the connection and would love to hear more about it. Or are you offering educational material? If so, am I your audience, or other folks? Or is there something else entirely going on?